# Is it possible to use NgxUiLoaderHttpModule & NgxUiLoaderRouterModule simultaneously in module. ts?

Tags: angular, spinner, ngx-ui-loader

I am working on angular 7 application. I am using NgxUiLoaderRouterModule to get spinner while routing, it works fine. But the spinner disappears before the data loads from http request. I tried to resolve by adding NgxUiLoaderHttpModule in module.ts.

Still spinner is not appearing till my request gets complete.

Comment: Have you tried using resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why NgxUiLoaderHttpModule not working is we were using http imported from '@angular/http' which is deprecated from ang 5 version. On updating http to httpClient (from '@angular/common/http) Spinner worked for me.